# Can I highlight an entire html tag using a shortcut in Notepad++?

Tags: html, selection, notepad++

I know you can highlight an entire row or a word, but I am looking for selecting an html tag with one click.

Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this plugin: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/HTMLTag/HTMLTag%20plugin%20v0.3/

Comment: Install plugin and CTRL + SHIFT + T